# What are GitHub's votes on black background?

Tags: github

[image: Github Black vote]

In the above picture, where does the black +9 vote come from? How do I add a +1 like this?

It is different from the comment reaction added recently to GitHub.

Comment: Is that from an issue comment?

Comment: yes, and I can observe it in several repositories.

Comment: Would you have a link to one? I've skimmed through several and can't find one that looks like that.